# Filter all product id of customers' first order

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset in which I have customer id's, order id's and product id's, like so

```
df <- data.frame(customerID=c(123,123,456,123,789,789,789,123,789),
                orderID=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6),
                Product_ID=c('A','B','C','C','D','D','E','C','D'))
```

| customerID | orderID | Product_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 123 | 1 | B |
| 456 | 2 | C |
| 123 | 3 | C |
| 789 | 4 | D |
| 789 | 4 | D |
| 789 | 4 | E |
| 123 | 5 | C |
| 789 | 6 | D |

I'm looking for a way to only keep the product id rows for every customers first order, like so:

| customerID | orderID | Product_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 123 | 1 | B |
| 456 | 2 | C |
| 789 | 4 | D |
| 789 | 4 | D |
| 789 | 4 | E |

I have tried

```
first_order <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(customerid) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1)
```

However, this gives me only the first row of a customerid, meaning it only returns one product id, where it can be possible for a order to include more than one product id.

I guess I should make changes to the `filter(row_number()==1)` statement, but I'm not sure how.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `first`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(customerID) %>% 
  filter(orderID == first(orderID))
```

---

In this case, using `slice_min` also works, assuming that the first order has the lowest number.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(customerID) %>% 
  slice_min(orderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`,

```
subset(df1, orderID %in% orderID[!duplicated(customerID)])
```

-output

```
   customerID orderID ProductID
1        123       1         A
2        123       1         B
3        456       2         C
5        789       4         D
6        789       4         D
7        789       4         E
```